# Create user without password using rest api

Tags: 8

From this [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services#users), currently what the User Registration resource does is to register a user that requires password in the Rest API.

Our goal is to call/use this api endpoint http://localhost:8080/user/register?_format=json to create a user once validated via facebook and dont want to have password in the json.

This is what Im getting when tried to remove the `pass` field

```
{
    "message": "No password provided."
}
```

from

```
{
"name": { "value": "test03" },
"mail": { "value": "test03@gmail.com" }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like when you create a user on user/register, the visibility/requiredness of the password field depends on the verify_mail setting.

If e-mail verification is enabled, then you must not provide a password, if disabled, you must provide one.